# After changing package name

Tags: android, admob

Hi guys I had never work on admob. I have one doubt if suppose I have one application on play store and suppose I lost my keystore I want to update my application therefore supposed I change package name and created new keystore then it is necessary to change admob id also? Or it is ok if I used old id.

I know it is considered as new application in play store. I will deactivate old package name after publishing new app.

Comment: afaik, you can use the same admob id for multiple application.

Comment: ok. Thank you very much